# a java exception has occurred when create a single jar from multiple jars using ant build.xml

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jar, build

A java exception has occured when create a single jar from multiple jars using ant build file. Currently i use the following code. I use 'Excelisor JET' for creating 'exe', but the file size is very large. Can any one help me..?

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project name="CIH_Billing" default="jar"> 
<target name="jar">
<zip destfile="output.jar">
<zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
<zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
</zip> 
</target>
</project>`
```

Comment: Can you post the exception ?

Comment: It just Show a message box that display "A java Excetion has occured" :( Thanks for you fast reply

Comment: restart the IDE and check.

Comment: Hi Sai Gowthami.. i restarted my IDE. Same issue still exists